# How do I compensate for the delay of smartphone screens?

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, delay

Is there a consistent way to compensate for the mechanical(?) delay between pressing the screen and the smartphone registering input?

E.g. creating a reaction time app, how is the delay compensated for? Is it a constant that is subtracted from the measured reaction time? Is there some way of calculating the exact delay for the given phone or is it consistent across different brands and screens on the market?

I see a significant delay (~100ms) in my testing using a phone.

Comment: how do you measure that `100ms` delay?

Comment: There is no way 100ms is accurate for a delay.  I have extreme doubts about your methodology.  If you're using onClick rather than raw MotionEvents you're doing it wrong-  clicks in android happen on the release of the touch not the beginning of the touch, which would be part of your problem.

Comment: @pskink By using measuring my reaction time, using any computer and seeing that my reaction time is considerably higher when measuring it using an app. It's very much an approximation with the 100ms, what I've tried to communicate is that it is considerable.

Answer (score 0):

100ms sounds like a lot, and definitely not what should/can normally occur. Depending on the phone's settings, the 'ink ripple' effect and similar animations that provide feedback on touches may be faster or slower to some extent, but this shouldn't affect the callbacks.

For testing any time sensitive actions, you probably don't want to run your app in `debug` mode, but build it in `profile` mode instead. Debug mode (evidently) lets you debug the app very well, by compiling code when it's needed on the device, which slows done especially on older devices or devices with low-end hardware. In `profile` mode, performance should be a lot better. If this doesn't help I'm not sure what's causing you trouble.

To run your app in `profile` mode, you can add the `--profile` flag to your `flutter run` command or the run configuration in e.g. Android Studio.

Here's some more information from the documentation about the build modes:
https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes